# Return the most recent date in a list column by referencing other Date columns within the list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to return the most recent date in a list column by referencing other Date columns within the list?

I am making a list that will track revisions on the same line item.  For example, there are columns for **Date Sent**, **Date Sent Rv1**, **Date Sent Rv2**, **Date Sent Rv3**, etc.  Each column contains the date the revision is sent.  I would like to reference all of these columns and return the most current date in another column **Latest Review Date Sent**.

It would be nice to know if this is even possible, and if it is, if I could be pointed in the right direction to accomplish this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MAX function and output it in Date format.

=MAX([date1],[date2],[date3])

If the Date fields are empty, write an if case to avoid garbage values.